EdgeからIEを開く方法は？
新旧システム移行中のため、古いシステムはIE、新しいシステムはEdgeで起動する別々のアプリケーションがあります。
IEはEdgeのIEモードではなく、純粋なIEが要件です。
親画面Edgeから子画面をIEで開く要件があるのですが、EdgeではActiveXコントロールが許可されておらず、以下のようなJavaScriptはエラー（ActivXObject is not defined）になってしまいます。
EdgeからIEでサブウィンドウを開く方法についてご存じの方がいらしたらご教授ください。
function subwindow(){
  let wss = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');
  wss.CurrentDirectory = "C:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/";
  let env = wss.Exec('iexplore.exe http://xxx/xxx');
}


手元の Windows 10 では iexplore.exe をダブルクリックしても Edge が起動する状態です。ActiveX 云々の前に、まず直接 IE が開く環境なのかも確認したほうが良さそうです。 / finction は function のスペルミスでしょうか？

カスタム URL スキームを利用して、IE を起動できないでしょうか？
ただし、個々の端末のレジストリへスキームとパスの登録が必要となります。
以下に設定の方法があります。

https://qiita.com/kojimadev/items/74100c8557a92939ef69

IE は、既に廃止になっており私の環境では試すことができませんので、確認いただければと思います。

情報提供ありがとうございます。開発機ならこの方法で実現できそうですが、現在ユーザ数が多く、個々の端末レベルでレジストリにURIスキームを登録するのは現実的ではなさそうです。別の方法で対応できるよう要件自体を変更したいと思います。
